# Twig and autoescaping

Tags: symfony, escaping, twig

I'm learning Symfony2. Currently, I'm trying to render a form label in a twig template. The label includes an html tag, that is not rendered correctly in my twig file.

Here follows the piece of code where the form field is created:

```
$builder->add('zipcode', 'integer', array(
        'label' => '<abbr title="Zone Improvement Plan">CAP</abbr> code',
        ));
```

In the twig file I render the field label as follows:

```
{{ form_label(form.zipcode) }}
```

I tried the raw, escape, e filters, but the results provided in my html page is always the string

```
 <abbr title="Zone Improvement Plan">CAP</abbr> code
```

and not the corresponding HTML code!

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance!

Later I found the solution. 
The solution is to disable the autoescape within the label block provided by Symfony at path: 
     symfony / src / Symfony / Bridge / Twig / Resources / views / Form / form_div_layout.html.twig

So, in your twig file you have to put the following lines outside the form:
    {% form_theme form _self %}

```
{% block generic_label %}
{% spaceless %}
  {% if required %}
      {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': attr.class|default('') ~ ' required'}) %}
  {% endif %}
  <label{% for attrname,attrvalue in attr %} {{attrname}}="{{attrvalue}}"{% endfor %}>{% autoescape false %}{{ label|trans }}{% endautoescape %}</label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [JeanValjean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1339429/jeanvaljean) himself :

```
{% autoescape false %}{{ form.zipcode.vars.label | trans }}{% endautoescape %}
```

And to generalize this behaviour to your whole app, you can override the form block for labels  :

```
{% block generic_label %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% if required %}
            {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': attr.class|default('') ~ ' required'}) %}
        {% endif %}
        <label{% for attrname,attrvalue in attr %} {{attrname}}="{{attrvalue}}"{% endfor %}>
            {% autoescape false %}{{ label|trans }}{% endautoescape %}
        </label>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I read at the [twig docs on autoescape][1] that "*Functions returning template data (like macros and parent) always return safe markup*".

So I guess that the problem is related to the form_label function. Hence, the solution is to rewrite this function to disable the autoescape!


  [1]: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/autoescape.html

Comment: However, the autoescape false option doesn't work in this case! As I mentioned in my question, I tried all the options described into the official Twig documentation.

Comment: :) Anyway, thanks for the interest! I think that the Twig docs has to be improved!

Comment: It's not about Twig but Symfony, as form_label, form_row, form_widget and so on are Symfony helpers based on Twig ;)

Comment: Yer, you have been precise! Symfony2 docs has to be improved! :)

Comment: I finally have found a fast & ugly shortcut. I'm new, so I cannot post it as a new solution. However, I want to share the solution I'm using. Simply, I use the {% autoescape false %}{{ form.zipcode.vars['label'] }}{% endautoescape %} code in the twig file. I also rewrited the {% block generic_label %} to let it automatic within my twig file.

Comment: I'm gonna edit my answer with your solution, and ask for moderation to give you reputation for this answer !

Comment: Wow thanks! Here is the full code: {% block generic_label %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if required %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': attr.class|default('') ~ ' required'}) %}
    {% endif %}
    <label{% for attrname,attrvalue in attr %} {{attrname}}="{{attrvalue}}"{% endfor %}>{% autoescape false %}{{ label|trans }}{% endautoescape %}</label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}

Comment: I don't think providing your block override is a good answer as it's better to keep escaping as default behaviour on a whole site. But the trick to call only form.field.vars.label is really useful for a particular case !

Comment: Well, I'm only disabling the autoescape for static html code that I provides through a private object. I do not give the possibility to such a user to send un-escaped codes... Moreover, the block override is suggested within the Symfony2 docs to customize forms! So, why block override is not a good choice?

Comment: It's probably a good choice for you, cause you know how you want to manage your labels, but disable autoescape for labels rendering doesn't seem to be a good answer for a ponctual use. I will add it as an alternative answer...

Comment: I'm just reasoning about the possibility to get some external attack by disabling the autoescaping in my way. Any theory?

Comment: As long as you keep control of your labels it's OK

Comment: Ok, thanks! That's sufficient for me. Moreover, this code will be used once over some dozens of Symfony forms.

Answer (score 8):

To disable the autoespace filter just to render a variable is not the best thing because when you read the code it's not really clear.

So, instead of :

```
{% autoescape false %}{{ label|trans }}{% endautoescape %}
```

You can use :

`{{ label|trans|raw }}`