# How to include javascript inside form widget in Symfony2

Tags: javascript, forms, symfony, twig, symfony-2.1

I would like to include JavaScript inside a form widget in Symfony2, but quotes are escaped inside the JavaScript command, see:

```
{{ form_widget(form.sdf, 
    { 'attr': { 'value': "document.MSketch.getMol('sdf');" } } 
) }}
```

and the result I get:

```
<input type="hidden" id="form_sdf" name="form[sdf]" required="required" value="document.MSketch.getMol(&#039;sdf&#039;);" />
```

I have read this topic : [Twig and autoescaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209345/twig-and-autoescaping)
But autoescape false is not working when using it like this:

```
{% autoescape false %}
{{ form_widget(form.sdf, 
    { 'attr': { 'value': "document.MSketch.getMol('sdf');" } } 
) }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

How to have quotes?

**EDIT:** Using raw filter isn't helping:

```
{% set cmd = 'document.MSketch.getMol("sdf");' %}
{{ form_widget(form.sdf, { 'attr': { 'value': cmd|raw } } ) }}
```

But raw filter is working outside of the form_widget, so where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to simply escape quotes? `\'` or `\"`

Comment: Simple escaping is not working. As a temporary fix, i put my JavaScript inside my submit button onclick attribute.